# losing variable in function

Tags: javascript

Could someone tell me why in the first `alert(items.index($(this))) = 1` and the second `alert(items.index($(this))) = -1`. How does this value get changed within the other function?

```
$(function () {
var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
        items.removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        alert(items.index($(this)));

        $('#v-nav>div.tab-content').fadeOut("slow", function () { 
        alert(items.index($(this)));
        $('#v-nav>div.tab-content').eq(items.index($(this))).fadeIn("slow");
        });


      //  window.location.hash = $(this).attr('tab');
    });
});
```

Comment: As it currently stands, I don't see a single `return` statement in the question. Are you having something else to disclose to us?

Comment: it would appear that your items variable wouldn't be populated until after your the each function has finished. Although I can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: I have re-phrased the question. It may make it clearer to the behaviour I am seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***`this` refers to current object.***

In first version,

`this` is an item of `$('#v-nav>ul>li')` list.

While in second version,

`this` is DOM object selected by `$('#v-nav>div.tab-content')`

If you want to retain the previous value of `this`, then cache it in a variable.
(Caching `$(this)` is a very good practise, as you always save a function call).

When you use `$(this)` you actually passes `this` into `$` function.

```
$(function () {
var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.click(function () {
        //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
        items.removeClass('current');
        $this.addClass('current');

        alert(items.index($this));

        $('#v-nav>div.tab-content').fadeOut("slow", function () { 
        alert(items.index($this));
        $('#v-nav>div.tab-content').eq(items.index($(this))).fadeIn("slow");
        });


      //  window.location.hash = $(this).attr('tab');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the callback function for the animation, `this` is not the element that you clicked, it's the element being animated.

> "The callback is not sent any arguments, but this is set to the DOM
>   element being animated."

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

(And if it hadn't been set to the animated element, it would have been a reference to the `window` object.)

Copy the reference to a variable outside the animation call:

```
var t = this;
$('#v-nav>div.tab-content').fadeOut("slow", function () { 
  alert(items.index($(t)));
  $('#v-nav>div.tab-content').eq(items.index($(t))).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the context of each "this", each of the callbacks has a distinct "this" variable.  If you want to keep the original this around, do something like:

```
var self = this;
```